# Capturing real time video with opencv in c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I'am developing a plate number detection application using opencv and c++.

For the detection trial, I want to capture real time video from my webcam using `VideoCapture()` function like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  // input image
  cv::Mat imgOriginalScene;      

  cv::VideoCapture cap = cv::VideoCapture(0); 

  for (;;) {
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap.read(frame);
    double timestamp = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);

    if (cap.read(frame)) {
      imgOriginalScene = frame;
      cv::Size size(1000, 600);
      resize(imgOriginalScene, imgOriginalScene, size);

      if (imgOriginalScene.empty()) {              
        std::cout << "error: image not read from file\n\n";   
        return(0);                        
      }

      std::vector<PossiblePlate> vectorOfPossiblePlates = 
          detectPlatesInScene(imgOriginalScene);    
      vectorOfPossiblePlates = detectCharsInPlates(vectorOfPossiblePlates);                 

      cv::imshow("imgOriginalScene", imgOriginalScene);      

      if (vectorOfPossiblePlates.empty()) {                         
        std::cout << std::endl << "no license plates were detected" << std::endl;    
      }
      else {                                      
        std::sort(vectorOfPossiblePlates.begin(), vectorOfPossiblePlates.end(), 
            PossiblePlate::sortDescendingByNumberOfChars);

        // suppose the plate with the most recognized chars
        // (the first plate in sorted by string length descending order) 
        // is the actual plate
        PossiblePlate licPlate = vectorOfPossiblePlates.front();

        cv::imshow("imgPlate", licPlate.imgPlate);      
        cv::imshow("imgThresh", licPlate.imgThresh);

        // if no chars were found in the plate
        if (licPlate.strChars.length() == 0) {                            
          // show message
          std::cout << std::endl << "no characters were detected" << std::endl << std::endl;    
        }

        // draw red rectangle around plate
        drawRedRectangleAroundPlate(imgOriginalScene, licPlate);        

        // write license plate text to std out
        std::cout << std::endl << "license plate read from image = " << licPlate.strChars << std::endl;   
        std::cout << std::endl << "-----------------------------------------" << std::endl;
        outfile << licPlate.strChars << "  " << timestamp / 1000 << " Detik" << std::endl;

        // write license plate text on the image
        writeLicensePlateCharsOnImage(imgOriginalScene, licPlate);        

        // re-show scene image
        cv::imshow("imgOriginalScene", imgOriginalScene);             

        // write image out to file
        cv::imwrite("imgOriginalScene.png", imgOriginalScene);          
      }
      cvWaitKey(34);
    }
    else {
      cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 1.0);
      cvWaitKey(1000);
    }
    if (cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) == cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) {
      break;
    }
  }

  outfile.close();

  // hold windows open until user presses a key
  cv::waitKey(0);         

  return(0);
}
```

But after running the code, the video shown from my webcam is stuck, like it just showing the very first frame and then stop. 
So I can't detect anything because the video is stuck.

Anyone facing the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, when reading from a camera the [steps are as follows](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html):

1. Open the cv::VideoCapture object and call `isOpened()` to verify successful open.  I generally prefer declaring the capture object separately and then using `open(0)` to open it, but test what works for you.
2. Read a frame into a `cv::Mat` object.  You can use `read()` or you could implement an approaching using the `<<` operator
3. Verify that the frame is not empty using `empty()`.
4. Process the image in your loop.

**Using waitKey()**

Remember that `waitKey(0)` will halt your program until the user presses a key.  Placing `waitKey(30)` once at then end of your loop will display the images in the processed and queued up using `imshow()`.  You do not need to use `waitKey()` multiple times throughout the loop and may want to you some other timer for timing purposes.

**Possible Error Points**

Your code may be hanging on your first if statement.  You are calling `cap.read(frame)` back to back which may be too fast for the webcam to process... causing it to return false after the first iteration.  Instead, try an implementation that uses `frame.empty()` instead to check if you have an image to process after calling `cap.read(frame)`.

```
cv::Mat imgOriginalScene;           // input image

cv::VideoCapture cap = cv::VideoCapture(0); 

if(!cap.isOpened()){
    cerr << "Error Opening Capture Device" << endl; //Use cerr for basic debugging statements
    return -1;
}

for (;;) {
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap.read(frame);
    double timestamp = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC);

    if (frame.empty()) {
         /*... do something ...*/
    }
    else {
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 1.0);
        cvWaitKey(1000);
    }
     //Try removing this for debug...
/*
    if (cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) == cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) {
        //break;

    }
*/  
    cv::waitKey(0);                 // hold windows open until user presses a key
}

outfile.close();
cv::waitKey(0);                 // hold windows open until user presses a key

return(0);
```

**Update Log:**

- Per @api55's comment, added the isOpened() check for completeness
- Added discussion for waitkey()
- Suggested commenting out sections that break the loop for now

Comment: Hi Mepix! thank you for your answer. I already did your suggestion, and yes the webcam is unable to open. And the documentation also didn't work. But, if i try with another code (with lighter computation) the webcam works fine. Still searching for answer for this problem

Comment: It never is the simple things, is it?  What other error messages do you get?  Just the video hanging?  What writes to `cout`?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the webcam can open but somehow the code unable to read the frame

Comment: It's not giving me any errors or warnings when I compile the program, but after compiling somehow it unable to read the frame :( .

Comment: What happens if you add a `cv::imshow` between `cap.frame()` and `double timestamp`?  I'm trying to understand why you aren't entering that first `if` statement

Comment: When I add cv::imshow between cap.frame() and double timestamp the result is the same. It's still unable to read the frame

Comment: You should check with isOpened after the constructor of videoCapture, sometimes it fails to open and you have to do it manually.

Comment: I already tried all you guys suggestions, but unfortunately the result still the same :(

Comment: Hi! I already find what is the the real problem here. And thank you for the suggestions, it's really helping me a lot :D